# Magento 2 Import - Advanced Pricing + 1000s of Products

Tags: magento2, import

Coming over from using MAGMI and Magento CE1.9, I suppose I was spoiled, as their import was able to have one product per row, with all the tiered pricing having their own row.. making it very easy and not an atrociously large painstaking file.

Now that I am transitioning into CE2.2.X, I am seeing that the pricing natively done through Magento is a little different, and assigns each tier its own row per product.

So the issue becomes, say having 8 different customer groups, all whom may have a different price for one product, and then having thousands of products.

That would be for instance, 16000 rows for a measly 2000 products which have 8 pricing tiers for assigned customer groups.

Aside from expensive extensions and the like, is there any better way? Is there a way to have the native Magento import read the csv for a column per different tier or is it destined to need a row per tier?

Comment: We have implemented import tier prices from same file in our paid commercial extension Improved Import & Export https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html